# How to add review comments on code in master branch

Tags: github

There is a repository on github, I have to review that. But all the code is there in the master branch. So I am unable to create any pull request for it as there is only one branch master and so not able to put any review comments on the code. Is there a way I can put review comments without opening a pull requests?
Or some alternative way to open a Pull request in this case?

I tried creating a pull request, but since there is only one branch its not possible. When I open a file directly on the github repository, I dont see any option to put comments.
An alternative I could think of is to create an empty branch and then create a PR. But could there be a better way?

Comment: Create a new branch from the commit immediately before the new changes. Then make a merge request from master to the new branch

Comment: There is only one commit in the master branch. So I think that won't be possible. Either I will have to delete the repository and create a new branch with modifications. Because the current master branch has 1 commit and that has it all

Answer (score 1):

0. So, you are on a `master` branch on GitHub.com
1. Open the file you want to review
2. Find the line where you want to leave a comment
3. Press "Blame"
4. Find out which commit has created/updated this line last time. Open this commit
5. When you opened the target commit from "blame", you are able to leave comments and mention author with `@`

Answer (score 0):

No clean way provided by the GitHub because of some design/implementation difficulties
Some workarounds and also the reason why GitHub can't provide this feature are given here - https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/211

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this without cloning the repo to your computer - from GitHub page for the repo:

1. Edit any file. For example, add an empty line to README.md. To do that:

   - Click on (for example) README.md on the main page.
   - Click on the pencil icon for "Edit this file" in the right top area.
   - Add a line at the end (or make any other edit).
2. Click "Commit Changes".
3. Add title and message for the commit and select "Create a new branch for this commit..." (see screenshot below).
4. Click "Propose Changes"
5. Click "Create a Pull Request".

[image]

---

> There is only one commit in the master branch. So I think that won't be possible. Either I will have to delete the repository and create a new branch with modifications. Because the current master branch has 1 commit and that has it all

It doesn't matter that there is only 1 commit. More often than not, when you create a branch, it is initially identical to another branch except for the name. In your case, you would be creating a new branch *from* branch `main` - essentially duplicating `main` under a new name.